# How to unwrap the original object from a dynamic proxy

Tags: java, reflection, proxy-classes, dynamic-proxy

what's the best approach to unwrap a dynamic proxy to retrieve the original object beneath?
The dynamic proxy has been created using `java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance()`

Thank you.

Comment: it depends how you've created it. Which library? the JDK Proxy? Or CGLIB/Javassist?

Comment: @Bozho: I've updated the question to be more precise

Comment: This supposes that there is an original object. What `InvocationHandler` is sent to `newProxyInstance()`?

Comment: I found very useful [this answer on another post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17695987/1504300). Furthermore, this question is a nearly-duplicate and it would be good to merge the suggestions in both IMHO

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each proxy has an [`InvocationHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) associated with it. Only the `InvocationHandler` knows which object (**if any**) underlies the proxy. If you control the creation of the proxy, then you can supply your own `InvocationHandler` that will have the extra functionality that you desire (i.e. will be able to disclose the underlying object.) If you don't, then I am afraid you're out of luck.

Answer (score 17):

There's no good method: Proxy.getInvocationHandler(proxy) returns handler, but the problem is to extract the original object from the handler. If your handler is an anonymous class, the only way to extract original object is to use reflection and extract original from field named val$something - very ugly method.
Better way is to create non-anonymous handler class with a getter, then you do:

```
((YourHandler)Proxy.getInvocationHandler(proxy)).getOriginalObject()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Proxy.getInvocationHandler(proxy) method to obtain the original InvocationHandler.

Comment: That's not the wrapped object.