# How would you expose type of implementing (not invocation handler!) class from proxy?

Tags: java, dynamic-proxy

How would you expose type of implementing class of an object regardless of whether it's real object or proxy ?

Here is example of the problem https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/issues/1523

I thought I could intercept `getClass` call in proxy but then I realized:

1) proxy intercepts only calls to interfaces defined as parameter to `Proxy.newProxyInstance`;
2) I can't override `getClass` in my interface because it's final.

I can of course add my own `getImplementingClass` to my interface and use it everywhere instead of `instanceof` but it looks hacky.

I can and know how to get class of invocation handler. But it (ReleasePermitOnComplete) is different from implementing class (WebSocketUpgradeHandler). Thus this question is more design question than simple question about how dynamic proxies work.

Ideas ?

Comment: Why? The whole idea of proxy classes is that they *conceal* the implementation.

Comment: @EJP I agree but `instanceof` has its valid use-cases. The question is how to continue using it regardless of whether it's proxy or not.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344299/how-do-i-get-the-underlying-type-of-a-proxy-object-in-java?

Comment: @lexicore I updated my question earlier this morning explaining why it's not duplicate :) But yeah, it may appear so.