# unable to get concrete class when it is proxified by Spring

Tags: java, proxy, spring-aop

i got something like that

```
 @Transactional
 public class ListController {

   @PersistenceContext
   EntityManager entityManager;


   @GetMapping("/save/avion")
   public ResponseEntity<String> save() {

        Avion avion = new Avion();
        entityManager.persist(avion);
   }

}
```

I just want to know name of implementation the Spring use for the EntityManager.
But i always obtain something lijke that..

I just tried 4 ways..

```
    System.out.println("==> " + entityManager.getClass());
    System.out.println("==> " + AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(entityManager));
    system.out.println("==> " + AopUtils.getTargetClass(entityManager).getName());
    System.out.println("==> " + entityManager.getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

but i systematically obtain..

```
    ==> class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110
    ==> class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110
    ==> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110
    ==> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110
```

So.. i can i obtain concrete class ?

Answer (score 0):

If the requriement is to obtain the name of the under factory bean , a `.toString()` on the `entityManager` bean would give that information.

Both

```
System.out.println(entityManager);
```

or

```
String entityManagerName = entityManager.toString();
System.out.println(entityManagerName);
```

would print in my test project

> Shared EntityManager proxy for target factory
> [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@4f7d3ab3]

Please go through the [article](https://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/spring-persistencecontext-explained/) (especially point 5 under section B Annotation processing
) to understand the framework code in detail.

Comment: absolutly correct BUT it returns to me concrete implementation of EntityManagerFactory, and not implementation of EntityManager, so i can't see code of my method persist().

Comment: Please go through this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344299/how-do-i-get-the-underlying-type-of-a-proxy-object-in-java)